# Ошибка в строке 9 Fatal Error PDOExeption

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, wamp-server

Честно скажу, что в PHP почти не шарю, это для курсовой. Есть код:

```
<?php
class Db
{
    public static function getConnection()
    {
        $paramsPath = ROOT . '/config/db_params.php';
        $params = include($paramsPath);
        $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']}";
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);
        $db->exec("set names utf8");
        return $db;
    }
}
```

При запуске через WAMP Server выдает следующее:

( ! ) Fatal error: in C:\wamp64\www\lib65664.local\components\Db.php on line 9
( ! ) PDOException: in C:\wamp64\www\lib65664.local\components\Db.php on line 9

Помогите пожалуйста, что тут не так? Проект могу скинуть куда удобно.

Comment: Полный текст ошибки дайте ...

Comment: Спасибо, уже решили вопрос, там надо было базу создать через php my admin.

Comment: Ответьте на свой вопрос, чтобы закрыть ...

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен, просто надо было добавить базу через PHP myAdmin